# How to install Solr 4.2.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 with Tomcat7

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, solr

I want to install `solr-4.2.1` with `tomcat 7` on `Ubuntu 12.04`, but Solr can't be started.

I've followed these steps:

1) I got tomcat7 by:

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat7 tomcat7-admin
```

2) I edited `tomcat-users.xml` with `sudo nano /etc/tomcat7/tomcat-users.xml`:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> 
    <tomcat-users> 
         <role rolename="manager"/> 
         <role rolename="admin"/>
         <role rolename="admin-gui"/> 
         <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
         <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager,admin,manager-gui,admin-gui"/>
    </tomcat-users>
```

3) Restart tomcat7: `sudo service tomcat7 restart`

4) download and untar solr-4.2.1 in `/usr/share/solr`

5) `sudo cp /usr/share/solr/example/webapps/solr.war /usr/share/solr/example/solr/solr.war`

6) `cd /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost`

7) `sudo nano solr.xml` and edited `solr.xml` with:

```
    <?xml version=’1.0’ encoding=’utf-8’?> 
    <Context docBase=”/usr/share/solr/example/solr/solr.war” debug=”0” crossContext=”true”> <Environment name=”solr/home” type=”java.lang.String” value=”/usr/share/solr/example/solr” override=”true” /> 
    </Context>
```

8) `sudo chown -R tomcat7 /usr/share/solr/example/solr`

9) `sudo service tomcat7 restart`

After that go to `http://localhost:8080/manager`, I login and push start button at Solr application and I receive the message:

> FAIL - Application at context path /solr could not be started
>
> FAIL - Encountered exception org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([after_stop]) for component [org.apache.catalina.startup.FailedContext@7bde993a] in state [FAILED]

Any ideas for this? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

while visiting http;//localhost:8080/manager it is not accepting username and password. Username and password are correct as tomcat-users.xml file.